# Docker angular instance can't get data from Docker express instance

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, docker, docker-compose

Through Docker compose I build up a set of images. Among them, there's a node.js/express server and an angularjs 2.0 frontend. 
Here's the docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.3"

services:

  angular:
    image: micheleminno/angular-client:latest
    build: ./angular-client
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"

  express:
    image: micheleminno/express-server:latest
    build: ./express-server
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - sql
      - nosql

  elasticsearch:
    build: elasticsearch/
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    networks:
     - nosql
    environment:
      - MAX_OPEN_FILES=1048576
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    command: echo "Elasticsearch disabled"

  kibana:
    build: kibana/
    volumes:
      - ./kibana/config/:/usr/share/kibana/config
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - nosql
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    command: echo "Kibana disabled"

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.5
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=real-affinities
      - MYSQL_USER=production
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=production
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - sql

  migrations:
    image: micheleminno/db-migrations:latest
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - sql

networks:

  nosql:
    driver: bridge
  sql:
    driver: bridge
```

When everything starts, loading page http://localhost:4200/ triggers the following GET request to the express server:

```
https://localhost:3000/target
```

but the request doesn't succeed:

[image]

[image]

Whereas if I do by myself the GET request, I can get results correctly:

[image]

### Update

Here's my CORS section in server.js:

```
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) in your Express Server. The CORS spec requires the OPTIONS call to precede the POST or GET if the POST or GET has any non-simple content or headers in it.

As you can see in your error pic, the `target` is a xhr OPTIONS request. See also the "Preflighted requests" section in the link above.

One possible and simple solution is to use the node.js package [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, can you see my update? What's wrong with that CORS configuration?

Comment: I switched that with the cors npm package you suggested, but same error..

Comment: Have you done something like `app.options( '/target', cors( corsOptions ) );` with `const corsOptions: any = {
      origin: '*',
      methods: [ 'GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS' ],
      headers: [ 'content-type' ],
    };`

Comment: See my answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I changed **https**://localhost:3000 to **http**://localhost:3000 as url for the http requests from angular client and now it works.